# SSRS Do Queries for Hidden Tables Run?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter that hides/shoes a table based on it's setting. If that table is hidden does the query behind it run?

Comment: If you want to conditionally circumvent the data set from a full query then you can modify your sql or stored procedure to examine a @ReturnNoData flag. It is not clean, however, it will prevent an expensive query from running (return immediately) when you would rather not have it run. -->WHERE (@ReturnNoData=0) AND (<Actual Where Clause>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does run. Dataset query assigned to table will run. you must be using some condition to hide the table, to get that condition processed values from dataset will be required, so the queries behind the table will run. 
if used condition doesn't need value from table dataset, your queries won't run.

Comment: In my case no values from the dataset are being used (I'm using a parameter to determine whether it will show/hide the table). So sounds like it won't run the query. (Which is good!)  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Yes.

I have a table with expressions that return boolean flags on a hidden table. I hide and show other features based on those values and it works fine regardless of it being hidden.